# Home page url rewriting Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I want to do a URL rewrite in the WordPress home page

I want to change my URL `http://mysite.loc/?pays=senegal` to look like `http://mysite.loc/senegal`.

The problem is that I am on the WordPress home page, so it will be confused with the URL of another page like `http://transfert.loc/page-example`.

I have already tried several optins but am completely blocked.

Here is my code example:

```php
public function rewrite_urls(){
        
         add_rewrite_tag( '%pays%','([^&]+)' );
         
         add_rewrite_rule(
            '([^/]+)',
            'index.php?pays=$matches[1]',
            'top'
        );
    }
```

Can someone help me please!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two problems I see- rewrite rules need to set query vars that will result in a successful main query. Setting just a custom var like slide doesn't parse to anything WordPress can load. Additionally, slide needs to be added to the recognized query vars for it to get parsed within a rule.

So, what would a rule look like that would load the front page posts in the main query? That's a good question- the posts page is a special case, the absence of any other query vars. I haven't found a way to do that with a rule, though it may exist.

An easier way to do this is with a rewrite endpoint:

```
function wpd_endpoint(){
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'page-example', EP_ROOT );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_endpoint' );
```

Keep in mind that if you have code accessing values via $_GET, this still won't work, because WordPress doesn't put query vars there when rules are parsed. You can change the code to use get_query_var, or just assign it before the code tries to access it:

```
$_GET['page-example'] = get_query_var('page-example');
```